# Backward Compatibility on the Pi 4

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-4

Is it possible to run Raspbian Stretch on the Pi 4?

The problem is that the newest released (Raspbian Buster) has some weird bug in which JavaFX applications cannot be started with the error : "***failed to add service - already in use?**"

Comment: I tried to boot Rpi4B with a microSD card with stretch.  But Rpi green LED blinks for one or two seconds and then hangs.  In other words, Rpi4B hates stretch! :(

Comment: can you post your `config.txt` contents

Comment: I've had the same message with a different program. Fix on the Pi was to switch to Full KMS. In my case it's fixed with Buster.

Comment: @kuzeyron thanks, your Full KMS suggestion solve partially my issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57328781/oracle-jre-8-on-raspberry-pi4). I've still got an error: "Could not initialize class com.sun.webkit.WebPage" inside a page where I have to display some web content (using WebPage tool of course). I'm using Liberica jdk11 with javaFx bundled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run Raspbian Stretch on Pi 4?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101353/can-i-run-raspbian-stretch-on-pi-4)

Answer (score 0):

I know of no reason why stretch couldn't work.

Nobody seems to have bothered to get it to work so you will have to do the heavy lifting yourself.

I would start by trying to find out why the Foundation chose to use Buster as the base for the Pi4.  If there is a show-stopper re stretch they should know.

Comment: I expected a more real life practical experience -_- this is because buster must run on pi 3b as well. It runs but almost an unusable experience. Raspbian buster has this stupid bug which is really a deal breaker for the pi4

Comment: I have a Pi4.  I don't have any deal breakers.  If enough people think your issue is important then it may be fixed.

Comment: because I am working on JavaFX project for raspberry pi and it doesn’t work on the pi 4 raspbian buster.

Comment: I read the question.  Is there a JavaFX site?  If so that might be a way to find people who also want to fix this problem.

Comment: @Joan I'd expect the show stopper is the new FKMS stuff and the kernel7i which aren't in Stretch. The RPF folks chose Buster as that was within two weeks of general availability when the RPi4B launched and it was probably easier to add the new stuff to the new version of Debian/Raspbian.

Comment: @Dougie Thanks for that.  I'll have to acknowledge my ignorance here as I have no idea what FKMS is.  Time for me to do a bit of googling.

Comment: @Dougie can't say I'm much the wiser after a quick google.  I'm headless and this technology has rather passed me by!

Comment: @Joan Most of my Raspberries run headless (the main 3B+ that doesn't has an official screen). All of this graphics stuff doesn't interest me enough either. Google isn't being my friend trying to find any sane documentation for KMS/FKMS etc.

Answer (score 0):

Stretch cannot run on the Pi 4; the foundation timed the release of the Pi 4 with the release of Buster to save money.

But... I have just released a [script](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=251757&p=1536647#p1536647) that will run a Raspbian Stretch virtual machine, inside the Raspbian Buster operating system. Not sure if it's helpful in your case, but definitely something to try.

Let me know how it goes.
[image: vdesktop script]