# Can I run Raspbian Stretch on Pi 4?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, pi-4

According to the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspbian), there is a yellow checkmark for Pi 4 for Stretch (if it is upgraded to the 2019-04-08 release).

I'm curious what limitations the Pi 4 has in this state.

Comment: Unfortunately when I took my Stretch SD card and ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` on a Pi 3 with it, it still does not boot my new Pi 4. Hmm.

Comment: Just copy the sd card image on a different pc. WIth the new sd card, you can't harm the original. Then on the raspberry pi 3, do a distro upgrade to buster. See what happens: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529547/upgrading-debian-9-stretch-to-debain-10-buster to set your repository to buster. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt dist-upgrade` - maybe they will still work after the upgrade? Worth a shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding is that there is new code required to support the RPi4 and that code is only delivered in Buster. If you need Stretch, you'll need to run it on earlier Pi hardware. You may get it to work, but why bother with possible limitations and degraded operation? If you have software that doesn't run on Buster, it's time to move it forward (or ask the developer to do so).

Comment: Yes, I once hoped that Stretch can run on my Rpi4, so I can run some old drivers which have not caught up with Buster.  But now I think I better be patient and wait for the old drivers to catch up soon.

Comment: This makes sense but I'm curious to know why there even is a yellow checkmark, as it doesn't seem to progress very far in the boot sequence. But it's possible that I did not upgrade the Stretch install properly.

Comment: could you provide a link referencing the "there is new code required to support RPi4"? I have the same understanding but I can't find where I'd originally read it.

Comment: @Marc Although not RPF confirmation, I did find this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=253283&p=1545413&hilit=jessie+pi4#p1545413 . This was my understanding as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have just released a [script](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=251757&p=1536647#p1536647) that will run a Raspbian Stretch virtual machine, inside the Raspbian Buster operating system. Not sure if it will work in your case, but it is definitely something to try if you don't want to wait for drivers to catch up.
[image: vdesktop script]